# save web.config error access denid

Tags: asp.net, web-config

i search but i cant find a solution for this problem.
when i want to save web.config i recieve this error:

An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'E:\vhosts\some.ir\httpdocs\egqz2vnh.tmp' is denied.

i use this code for access and save webconfig:

```
     var config = Misconfiguration.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
config.AppSettings.Settings["name"].Value = txt1.Text;

    config.Save();
```

i use Plesk for upload website.do need set permission for current user to access web.config in ftpaccess?

any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your website folder permssion.
For example with plesk  (in file manager), I clicked on "change access right to the file or directory" (for website container directory , not web.config). Then I changed permissions on "Default Plesk application pool user (IWAM_plesk(default))".

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Configuration;

Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
string oldValue = config.AppSettings.Settings["name"].Value;
config.AppSettings.Settings["name"].Value = "ABC";
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

 <appSettings>
    <add key="name" value="XYZ" />
 </appSettings>
```

after the execution value field would be changed to ABC.

Comment: when i run code in localhost no error.but on server error was occured.

Comment: icacls E:\vhosts\some.ir\httpdocs /grant:r "IIS APPPOOL\mywebsitepool":(OI)(CI)(RX) --Try executing this command from cmd ,change mywebsitepool by your application pool name

Comment: open command prompt and execute this line -- icacls E:\vhosts\some.ir\httpdocs /grant:r "IIS APPPOOL\mywebsitepool":(OI)(CI)(RX)

Comment: i run this and result is:no mapping bitween account names and security ids was done .successfuly proccessd 0 files failed proccessing 1 file

Comment: If that command is executed succeessfully then please try above code once again.

Comment: but it is failed!what can i do?